# Log pattern provided in log4j.properties file is not being used

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, slf4j

I am using **slf4j** logging library and have provide logging pattern in **log4j.properties** file under **resources** folder in my maven project but still the pattern I have provided does not take affect and is printed with default logging pattern.

i am using slf4j logging library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.26</version>
</dependency>
```

I am initializing the logger by

```
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CurrentClassName.class);
```

My log4j.properties file content is

```
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, STDOUT, file
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.STDOUT.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p[] [%t] (%F:%L) - %m%n
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%-5level] [%-30logger{20}] [${application.name}] [%X{request_id}] - %msg%n"
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=mylogs.log
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
#log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%-5level] [%-30logger{20}] [${application.name}] [%X{request_id}] - %msg%n"
```

ACTUAL LOG OUTPUT

```
11:07:45.091 [main] DEBUG com.abc.def.LoggingClassName - message logged from within the class
```

Expected LOG OUTPUT

```
2019-07-17 12:03:59 [INFO ] [c.b.CurrentLoggingClassName      ] [aplication-name] [] - message logged from class
```

**P.S.**

I have also tried renaming the **log4j.properties** file to **log4j2.properties**

And I have also tried both properties file placing under **/src** folder one by one

Answer (score 0):

try using this

appender.console.type = Console

appender.console.name = STDOUT

appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout

appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

Comment: go through this https://springframework.guru/log4j-2-configuration-using-properties-file/

Comment: its not a spring project